# Automated testing of chained Queueable jobs in Salesforce

Tags: queueable-interface, queueable-apex, asynchronous-testing, queueable

I am currently writing a queueable class for asynchronous processing in my triggers since triggers do not allow callouts. I am going achieve it by calling a class which implements the queueable interface.
When reading the documentation I found out that you can have 50 queueable in one transaction but can call only one queueable from a queueable class.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm

Also, I can not chain the queueable jobs in apex test.
[image: Salesforce documentation for chaining queueables in apex tests]

Example of working class / method:
Below class will work in its own transaction.

```
EventTriggerHandler.afterInsert(){
  Boolean bDoACallout = isCalloutNecessary();
  if(bDoACallout){
    System.enqueueJob(new EventTriggerHandlerCallout((Map<Id, Event>)Trigger.newMap));
   }
  Boolean bSecondCondition = isSecondConditionTrue();
  if(bSecondCondition){
    System.enqueueJob(new Trial1Queueable((Map<Id, Event>)Trigger.newMap));
   }
  Boolean bThirdCondition = isThirdConditionTrue();
  if(bThirdCondition){
    System.enqueueJob(new Trial2Queueable((Map<Id, Event>)Trigger.newMap));
  } 
}
```

Now, Salesforce documentation says, above mentioned code will work but wont be testable and I need to wrap it around Test.isRunningTest() and I may be wrong but what I understood from that is, these queueables needs to be tested separately and not in the test of EventTriggerHandler itself.

```
EventTriggerHandler.afterInsert(){
  Boolean bDoACallout = isCalloutNecessary();
  if(bDoACallout){
    System.enqueueJob(new EventTriggerHandlerCallout((Map<Id, Event>)Trigger.newMap));
   }
  Boolean bSecondCondition = isSecondConditionTrue();
  if(bSecondCondition){
    System.enqueueJob(new Trial1Queueable((Map<Id, Event>)Trigger.newMap));
   }
  Boolean bThirdCondition = isThirdConditionTrue();
  if(bThirdCondition){
    System.enqueueJob(new Trial2Queueable((Map<Id, Event>)Trigger.newMap));
  } 
}
```

This was working on its own as expected all the unit tests were working too per my understanding of queueable class and apex tests. Above code will not work when Event is being created from a queueable itself. We did a clean up exercise to consolidate all the logic in one queueable class. 
But, I am not sure how to code a smoke test / automated tests so that we  catch these beforehand without manual tests of entire org.

Comment: if response of 1st condition triggers queuebale of second, why not make callouuts first and then do DML?

Answer (score 6):

When you need more than one execution, but you want to test the asynchronous code independently, you can cheat by rolling them back. Here's an example in a unit test:

```
Test.startTest();
SavePoint sp = Database.setSavePoint();

// Replace this with real code
executeTheTrigger();

// Do any asserts, etc...

// Roll back the transaction
Database.rollback(sp);
Test.stopTest();
```

Then, you can get a natural 100% coverage of your trigger code without this error. Note that you should prefer to do any assertions before you roll back the state, since any modifications will disappear. Also remember you'll need to unit test your Queueables independently.

Answer (score 5):

A quick note to start off, the code you've provided right now doesn't display chaining of queueable classes. Chaining would be that you set up the execution of a queueable class from inside the `execute()` method of another queueable class. Rather, you have shown us a *sequence* of queueable calls.

A class that implements the `Queueable` interface, and the `execute(QueueableContext ctx)` method required to be in it, aren't really that different from any other class/method.

The `QueueableContext` parameter, which [has official documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_system_queueablecontext.htm), doesn't end up doing much of anything for you. It contains a job id, and nothing else (from what I can tell).

You can call the `execute()` method synchronously by simply passing in `null` as the argument for the `execute()` method (provided that you aren't actually using the job id).

So, in this case, testing your chained queueable methods breaks down to simply testing each method one at a time (likely in different test methods). You'll need to set up your test environment appropriately so that you are guaranteed to take the code path(s) that you want to test, but that's no different from your ordinary, run-of-the-mill unit test.

You may need to keep the chained calls behind a check against `test.isRunningTest()`, but that's about it.

You *could* possibly write a test that calls your queueable class from your trigger handler (not sure if you can call more than one per test), but that'd be less of a unit test, and more like an *integration test*.

### +edit:

To write a test for your trigger handler that is closer to being a unit test, you should look into [the Stub API to mock your calls](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_stub_api.htm) to your queueable classes. The idea here is that you'll only care that the queueable class has its `execute()` method called (and not the result of running the actual code, which would be a unit test of the queueable classes themselves)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have queueable because I want to make callouts in the after triggers. By calling the execute() synchronously, I wont be able to make callouts to outside systems in the trigger.

Comment: @JsonBourneShell you can make at least one (maybe more, I'm not 100% sure right now) call to a queueable class in a unit test if you make use of `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()` as part of your test method. The point still stands, though, that testing the functionality of your queueable classes in your test for your trigger handler is closer to integration testing than unit testing.

Comment: Yes, you've hit the nail on the head here. I am looking for a way to write automated smoke / integration test so that I will be able to catch it beforehand.

Comment: N.B. GITHUB apexmocks being a more leveraged approach IMHO than building the stub API framework for one use case